# Mac Terminal: How to view a microsoft word file? (It says it is binary)

Tags: macos, ms-word, terminal

So I was writing a paper on Microsoft Word and the file is corrupt now. I'm trying to see if I can open the file using vim, but it says it is binary. Is there any command or any way to convert it into text so that I can just `vim myfile.doc` and copy the text contents? I tried doing a `cp myfile.doc myfile.txt` to change the extension but it still says it's binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.doc` or `.docx` is not a plane `txt` file. It has several formatting and a bit of binary and in `.docx` xml factor included.

You can go for [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) which is Free.

Answer (score 1):

A doc file is a proprietary format by Microsoft. Docx formats are xml based but neither can be read directly using a text editor. If your file is corrupt you're probably going to have a lot more luck try to find the autosave location or try and recover the document using the tool office provides. In future remember to back up your work ;)

Answer (score 1):

/usr/bin/strings may be helpful -- built-in to OS X. Hope you can recover your paper.

Comment: `man strings` will tell you more detail, but in short, it lets you see whatever characters are ASCII in a binary file.

Comment: nice to know. but it didn't print out anything useful

Comment: I'm not God, Edmund, just another StackOverflow user trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Antiword to convert to .txt if it can still access the file properly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiword

Answer (score 0):

Word itself has an option to "Recover Text From Any File" which is worth trying if you haven't done so already. When you open the file in Word, if it doesn't recognise the format, you should see a conversion dialog and the option is in there. You might have to check the "Confirm conversion at open" option (e.g. "Word Preferences->General->Confirm conversion at open" on Mac Word 2011, "File->Options->Advanced->General->Confirm file format conversion on open" on Windows Word 2010.